# MatConvNet is not compiling for GPUs

Tags: compilation, gpu, deep-learning

I have the following problem when I want to compile matconvnet for GPUS:

> > vl_compilenn('enableGpu', true)

```
vl_compilenn:   CUDA: MEX config file: '/home/anselmo/Experimentos-Impressora-DeepLearning/matconvnet-master/matlab/src/config/mex_CUDA_glnxa64.sh'

mex:  no file name given.

Usage:
  MEX [option1 ... optionN] sourcefile1 [... sourcefileN]
  [objectfile1 ... objectfileN] [libraryfile1 ... libraryfileN]

 Use the -help option for more information, or consult the MATLAB External Interfaces Guide.

 Error using mex (line 206)
 Unable to complete successfully.

 Error in vl_compilenn>mex_compile (line 434) 
 mex(mopts{:}) ;

 Error in vl_compilenn>(parfor body) (line 393)
 mex_compile(opts, srcs{i}, toobj(bld_dir,srcs{i}), flags.mexcu) ;

 Error in parallel_function (line 470)
    F(base, limit, supply(base, limit));

 Error in vl_compilenn (line 387)
 parfor i = 1:numel(horzcat(lib_src, mex_src))

 509         rethrow(E)
```

What can be happening?

Comment: Check your GPU driver and CUDA toolkit version